# Che legni sono il cianno e il vosso?

Tags: word-meaning

In un passo del suo *De viribus quantitatis*, Luca Pacioli (1447-1517) descrive come costruire una clessidra molto precisa, che dev'essere composta da due bocce di vetro tra le quali scorre del mercurio. Tra le due bocce ci dev'essere una lamina con un piccolo buco, e secondo lui la lamina non dev'essere fatta di metallo, bensì

> vol essere de vetro o vero de alcun legno denso, cianno, vosso et oliva, pero etc.

Quindi il “cianno” e il “vosso” sono due dei legni densi adatti a questa parte della bussola. Sapete che cosa siano, in termini moderni?

(Il Treccani riporta il [ciano](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/ciano), con una “n”, come nome alternativo del fiordaliso, nonché dell'ambretta, nome che a sua volta designa varie specie vegetali, ma che mi sembra che siano tutte erbe.)

Comment: Ulteriori ricerche mi fanno temere che per il “cianno” ci sia poco da fare: nell'articolo “Scavi lessicali nel _De viribus quantitatis_ di Luca Pacioli” di Enzo Mattesini (in _Pacioli 500 anni dopo_ a c. di Enrico Giusti e Matteo Martelli, disponibile in rete: https://www.centrostudimariopancrazi.it/images/pubblicazioni/pacioli_500_anni_dopo/pacioli_500_anni_dopo_volume.pdf), a proposito di questa parola l'autore dice testualmente “non trovo riscontri” (p. 158).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il vosso potrebbe essere il [bosso](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buxus), che, sebbene sia un arbusto, ha un legno con utilizzi compatibili con ciò che viene descritto nella domanda:

> Il legno di bosso, di colore giallastro e molto duro, è pregiato e di
>   facile lavorabilità; viene utilizzato per lavori di ebanisteria, pezzi
>   degli scacchi, bocce da gioco, intaglio, strumenti musicali e nel
>   modellismo navale. In forma di stecchi, il legno di bosso è ampiamente
>   utilizzato in orologeria per la pulizia dei movimenti d'orologio.

Comment: Giusto, suona molto probabile, grazie.